# Django: Parent categories doesn't shown in admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

**Problem:**
Dash signs display in 'Parent category' column before I open any menu item. I get 'Parent category' items when open menu item profile(see `admin.py` below)

Before and after opening of menu profile: [picture1](https://ibb.co/fuCZHb) and [picture2](https://ibb.co/kPgYAw) (pay attention on Parent Category column)

**My `models.py`:** (attention on `parent_id`)

```
class Menu(models.Model):

    cat_title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Category title')
    menu_title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Menu title')
    parent_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Parent category', choices=(('',''),))
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='URL', blank=True)
    named_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Named URL', blank=True)
    level = models.IntegerField(default=0, editable=False)
```

**My `admin.py`:** ()

```
class MyMenu(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_choices(self):
        choices = (('',''),)
        categories = models.Menu.objects.all().values()
        for i in categories:
            choices += ((i['id'], i['cat_title']),)
        return choices

    def formfield_for_choice_field(self, db_field, request):
        if db_field.name == 'parent_id':
            db_field.choices = self.get_choices()

        return super().formfield_for_choice_field(db_field, request)
    list_display = ('cat_title', 'menu_title', 'parent_id', 'level')
    list_display_links = ('cat_title', 'menu_title')

    admin.site.register(models.Menu, MyMenu)
```

**Question:** How could I rewrite my `admin.py` to show `parent_id` items without opening any menu item profile?

I've already tried [`Model.get_FOO_display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) but it doesn't work in right way. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing your model, the simplest solution is probably to add a `parent` method in your admin and use it instead of "parent_id" in the `list_display` list:

```
class MyMenu(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ....
    def parent(self, obj):
        if obj.parent_id:
            return Menu.objects.get(pk=obj.parent_id).cat_title
        return ""

    list_display = ('cat_title', 'menu_title', 'parent', 'level')


    # Unrelated but you may also want to rewrite `get_choices`
    # in a simpler and more performant way:
    def get_choices(self):
        choices = models.Menu.objects.values_list("id", "cat_title"))
        return (('',''),) + tuple(choices)
```

Or to make `parent` a method or property on your `Menu` model:

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    # ...

    # you may want to use django's `cached_property` instead
    # but then you'll have to invalidate the cache when setting
    # (or unsetting) `.parent_id`
    @property
    def parent(self):
        if not self.parent_id:
            return None
        return Menu.objects.get(pk=self.parent_id)
```

and add "parent" to your admin's `list_display`.

BUT since `Menu.parent_id` is actually a foreign key on `Menu`, the proper solution is to declare it as such in your model:

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    cat_title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Category title')
    menu_title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Menu title')
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True, related_name="children")
    # etc
```

Comment: Great. Works as I expected. Thanks!